# calculating number of test cases for given number of parameters

Tags: testing, combinations, combinatorics

I am reading book Embedded Software Development for software critical systems about combinatorial testing.

Suppose if we have 11 parameters that we can configure the operating system, and each parameter had 5 possible values (for a total of 48,828,125 possible tests, were the system to be tested exhaustively).

Note: Here t is the strength" of the testing (all combinations of t of the parameters).

With t = 2 (i.e., all possible combinations of every pair of parameters), there must be at least 5 * 4 = 20 test cases and, For t = 3, there must be at least 5 * 4 * 4 = 80 test cases.

My question is how we author got 5 *4 for t =2 and 5 *4 *4 for t=3? Is there any generic formula present? Kindly help me to understand.

Thanks for your time and help